# VBA ExportAsFixedFormat to PDF for a range and changing display of output

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code which outputs my desired range to a PDF files and correctly fits it to one portrait page:

```
 With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
End With

rng.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=fSName, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

However, on my PDF I have row letters on the left and an extra blank bar above my titles like so:

[image]

How can I get rid of these? I do not want them displayed and they have only appeared since I have added this section:

```
 With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintHeadings = False
```

to get rid of these column and row headings.

---

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
    .PrintHeadings = False
End With
```